# Modifying Jira Server Add-on for Jira Cloud instances

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I have developed Jira Server add-on/plugin for Jira 7 which now needs to be installed into a cloud instance of Jira. However on the marketplace-page of my plugin it says:

> This hosting is not available for this add-on.

What do I have to do to make my plugin installable into a cloud instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manner to create an add-on on Jira cloud is totally different from the one with Jira server. In this case, you need to extend and integrate with Atlassian Connect.

In fact, with jira cloud, your add-ons are web applications that are integrated into Jira via iframes. You can find the Atlassian connect documentation here: https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/index.html.

The [Hello World tutoral](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/tutorials/connect-basics.html) is very useful to understand how Atlassian Connect works.

Note that Atlassian connect works for Confluence Cloud too.